# Class must be declared abstract or implement abstract method

Tags: android, opencv

I have a simple project that just show the camera with org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.

and I am getting this following error with red underline:

Class 'HelloVisionActivity' must be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onCameraViewStopped()' in CvCameraViewListener2'

on 
public class HelloVisionActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2

this is a part of my code:

```
public class HelloVisionActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {  


private static final String  TAG = "Example::HelloVisionWorld::Activity";
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;


public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {


    return inputFrame.rgba();
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_vision);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.HelloVisionView);

    //Set the view as visible
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);


    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();


    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_8, this, mLoaderCallback);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hello_vision, menu);
    return true;
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override

    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {

            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This interface `CvCameraViewListener2`
has a method named `onCameraViewStopped()`... you need to override it in the HelloVisionActivity  activity..

## Example:

```
    public class HelloVisionActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {  
    
    private static final String  TAG = "Example::HelloVisionWorld::Activity";
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    
        return inputFrame.rgba();
    }

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped(){
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too and I found out the solution.

```
public class HelloVisionActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {  


private static final String  TAG = "Example::HelloVisionWorld::Activity";
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
private Mat mRgba; //Insert this in your code
```

Next, insert the following code and your problem will be solved.

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped(){
    mRgba.release();
}
```